# Project Euler #4 repeat of numbers generated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve Project Euler Problem #4 and while I have solved it I am not satisfied with my code because it generates repeats.

Below is the code:

```
pal = []

for i in range(100 ** 2, 1000 ** 2):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        pal.append(i)

for n in pal:
    for x in range(100, 1000):
        if 99 < n / x < 1000 and n % x == 0:
            print(x, n//x, n)

# largest palindrome product of two 3-digit numbers
```

When I run this code, I get repeats ie. multiples of the same palindrome product. For example, it will return 840048 twice, which is a product of 888 and 946. Is there a way to not generate repeats with this code?

EDIT 1: part of my build output

```
946 888 840048
869 982 853358
982 869 853358
894 957 855558
957 894 855558
924 932 861168
```

Comment: You could always check if the number has already been found and not re-add it.

Comment: @nbryans Is there a way to check what has been printed out? Or do I have to make a list/set of the palindrome products to do that?

Comment: are you aware that a `set` works a lot like a list but doesn't have order or repeat values?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I was not, thanks a lot. I just started learning and didn't know a lot about set since most I have been using are strings and lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you `set` or to store values just once:

```
pal = set()

for i in range(100 ** 2, 1000 ** 2):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        pal.add(i)

for n in pal:
    for x in range(100, 1000):
        if 99 < n / x < 1000 and n % x == 0:
            print(x, n//x, n)
```

Comment: *Deprecated since version 2.6*, though

Comment: Wow the `sets` module has been removed for quite some time now and deprecated for ages before that. `set` has been a builtin type for quite a while... so `pal = set()` is how to do it now...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there however a way to make it so that my two 3-digit numbers that form the product is shown as well?

Comment: You mean you want to store them in the set? They are already shown.

Comment: @ΔλЛ using my previous code, the two 3-digit numbers are shown together with the product. See EDIT 1.

Comment: Well, using the snippet I've posted, the 3-digit numbers are also shown

Comment: @ΔλЛ sadly the numbers are repeated @.@

Comment: @Larrrrrrrrrry if you want each element of `pal` to show at most only once then add a `break` after the print statement to break out of the inner loop and move on to the next `n in pal`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen THANKS A LOT. That was what I was looking for this whole time. I did not know that adding a break there made a difference.